# Can we find variance from CDF directly

Tags: probability, probability-theory, probability-distributions

I need to find the variance of a random variable using the CDF of the random variable. I do not want to calculate pdf from CDF.

I will be very thankful for any help

BR

Frank

Comment: Try integration by parts.

Comment: Can you write the general mathematical formula?

Comment: $E(X^2)=\int_0^\infty 1-F(\sqrt t)+F(-\sqrt t)\,dt$, $E(X)=\int_0^\infty 1-F(t)-F(-t)\,dt$.

Comment: @A.S. I think it would be nice if you expanded this comment into an answer.

Comment: can you provide the reference A.S..

Comment: Use $E(X)=\int_0^\infty 1-F(t)\,dt$ for non-negative $X$ which can be show by changing the order of integration.